# jQuery: Simple, lightweight modal box

Tags: jquery, plugins

What is the simplest jquery plugin for modalboxes that do the following:

1. Ajax by href Inline content modal
2. Simple slide-down effect
3. Little supplied styling (I don't
   want it wrapped in 15 divs of junk)

Thanks!

I've tried jQuery UI's dialog, but it's becoming problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) is a great plugin, and it seems to be the one recommended by the awesome crew (including a core jQuery member) over at [yayQuery](http://yayquery.com/).

Comment: ...although it doesn't look like it has the "slide-down" effect out of the box. I'd say it's still worth checking out though if you can compromise on the exact behavior of it.

Comment: @Kevin - what did you move to?

Comment: I tried jQuery UI dialog...but it's just causing problems.  I'm trying to scale down my jquery plugins...Colorbox worked, but for my app, it'd be really nice if it were a slide-down dialog.

Answer (score 1):

overlay component in **jquery tools**:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html

Comment: Good, but it doesn't have ajax supported, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest one I have found, while still having some nice functionality,  is
[Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

It is pretty simple to use and still has some nice functionality.  If you want crazy simple you could just style a div to float in the middle of the page and then unhide it via jquery.

Comment: Well you can put links and buttons in the modal popup that then link to functions that perform ajax calls.  JQuery already helps you out a lot with that.  I don't think the plugin provides additional abstraction to help you with the ajax calls though.